# What is undefined symbol: X509_EXTENSION_free?

Tags: c++, openssl

I tried to create a library on linux that uses openssl. When I try to load this dll (*.so on linux) I am getting "undefined symbol: X509_EXTENSION_free" as error. I am bit confused whether its an issue with Openssl or my code implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are missing a `-lcrypto` when creating your shared library.

Comment: did you mean to say that I should include -lcrypto in the makefile for my library

Comment: Yes, you need to link every binary that uses this function against that library.